# Animate multiple elements sequentially using only CSS3 + SASS

Tags: html, css, animation, sass

I have a list of *n* HTML elements and I need to animate them one after another **using only CSS3 and SASS**. For example:

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li> // Fade in on element load
    <li>2</li> // Fade in one second later
    <li>3</li> // Fade in one second later
        .
        .
        .
    <li>n</li> // Fade in at last
</ul>
```

Note that there isn't a fixed number of items so it should work with *n* elements.

I already know how to do it using JS, but I wonder if it's possible to do this using only CSS3 and SASS.

I'm currently trying some ideas so if I find a solution for this I'll definitely post it here.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes this is possible only trough css. But not dynamically. To have each element follow the last with a 1 second delay, you'll need to use javascript.

Comment: I think the person who voted to reopen the question doesn't even look to the duplicate ... it's a perfect duplicate and the solution is present in the question before getting more options within the answer ... @Andres Root, since you are using sass you can ue the solution of the delay an easily write it with SASS

Comment: @TemaniAfif Correct, the post you pointed out has the solution for my problem. Thanks!